# SQL count two columns and substract

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, unpivot

Good night. I got this problem, I tried sub querys and case with no success.

When a player kill someone in my game, a new record is added to database, this record contains the ID of the killer and the ID of the killed player, so after a while table will look like this:

```
killer_id  |  death_id
100        |  200        -> (Player 100 Killed player 200)
100        |  200
100        |  200
200        |  100
300        |  100
300        |  200
```

Im trying to get the score of every player, based on their kills minus their deaths, so based on the above data:

```
Rank:
Pos 1. player 300 / 2 Points  (2 Kills - 0 deaths)
Pos 2. player 100 / 1 Point   (3 Kills - 2 deaths)
Pos 3. player 200 / -3 Points (1 Kills - 4 deaths)
```

I want to do this on one SQL query, but I'm stuck... any tip would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select player_id, sum(cnt) score
from (
    select killer_id player_id, 1 cnt from mytable
    union all select death_id, -1 from mytable
) t
group by player_id
order by score desc
```

If you also want the player rank, you can use window functions (this requires MySQL 8.0):

```
select rank() over(order by sum(cnt) desc) pos, player_id, sum(cnt) score
from (
    select killer_id player_id, 1 cnt from mytable
    union all select death_id, -1 from mytable
) t
group by player_id
order by score desc
```

Comment: thank you I'm not an expert on sql so this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select player_id, sum(points)
from ((select killer_id as player_id, 1 as points
       from t
      ) union all
      (select death_id, -1 as points
       from t
      ) 
     ) kd
group by player_id
order by sum(points) desc;
```